# typo3 PHP process causes hangup: Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - session is not active

Tags: php, typo3

administrator protocoll (1.+2.) shows the following errors. After stopping and restarting PHP-Process by the webhoster typo3 works fine. php-fpm_slow.log (3.) Any ideas?

1.

> Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - session is not active in /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/typo3/sysext/install/Classes/Service/SessionService.php line 165

SessionService.php line 165

```
/**
     * Generates a new session ID and sends it to the client.
     *
     * @return string|false the new session ID
     */

    private function renewSession()
    {
        // we do not have parallel ajax requests so we can safely remove the old session data
        **session_regenerate_id(true);**
        return session_id();
    }
```

2. 

> Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3temp/var/session/5b746183ce7e94a328dc1c5bb6e5598574a6d5c1/hash_6e60e04342f6660702e7abff85ff99d9 in /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/typo3/sysext/install/Classes/Service/Session/FileSessionHandler.php line 210

FileSessionHandler.php line 210

```
   /**
     * Garbage collect session info. See @session_set_save_handler
     *
     * @param int $maxLifeTime The setting of session.gc_maxlifetime
     * @return bool
     */
    #[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
   
 public function gc($maxLifeTime)
    {
        $sessionSavePath = $this->getSessionSavePath();
        $files = glob($sessionSavePath . '/hash_*');
        if (!is_array($files)) {
            return true;
        }
        foreach ($files as $filename) {
            **if (filemtime($filename) + $this->expirationTimeInMinutes * 60 < time()) {**
                @unlink($filename);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

3. 

Protokoll

```
[27-Jun-2022 19:02:20]  [pool wxxxxxxx] pid 3601
script_filename = /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/index.php
[0x00007f6b0e2163f0] curl_exec() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php:44
[0x00007f6b0e216350] __invoke() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php:28
[0x00007f6b0e2162a0] GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/Proxy.php:48
[0x00007f6b0e2161f0] GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/PrepareBodyMiddleware.php:35
[0x00007f6b0e216110] __invoke() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php:31
[0x00007f6b0e216060] GuzzleHttp\{closure}() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RedirectMiddleware.php:71
[0x00007f6b0e215fc0] __invoke() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php:63
[0x00007f6b0e215f20] GuzzleHttp\{closure}() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php:75
[0x00007f6b0e215e90] __invoke() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:331
[0x00007f6b0e215d40] transfer() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:168
[0x00007f6b0e215c60] requestAsync() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php:187
[0x00007f6b0e215bd0] request() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/RequestFactory.php:55
[0x00007f6b0e215b30] request() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Middleware/StaticRouteResolver.php:131
[0x00007f6b0e215a80] getFromUri() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Middleware/StaticRouteResolver.php:186
[0x00007f6b0e215990] resolveByType() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Middleware/StaticRouteResolver.php:72
[0x00007f6b0e215890] process() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php:172
[0x00007f6b0e2157f0] handle() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/typo3/sysext/adminpanel/Classes/Middleware/AdminPanelInitiator.php:55
[0x00007f6b0e215760] process() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php:172
[0x00007f6b0e2156c0] handle() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/Middleware/SiteBaseRedirectResolver.php:94
[0x00007f6b0e2155c0] process() /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3_src-11.5.11/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/MiddlewareDispatcher.php:172
```

Comment: Is the file where `filemtime()` failed actually there? If yes this might be a dirty PHP realpath cache. Since you say that restarting php-fpm solves that, that also points in that direction. Are you using symlink-switching deployment by any chance? Does the problem go away after some time (2 min is the default realpath cache lifetime)?

Comment: Hi Jonas, thanks for answering and yes indeed, the file is already there:  FileSessionHandler.php is a system file, located in the typo3/sysext/install/Classes/Service directory. I suppose the error could be related to the "staticfilecache" extension. For this I had added the .htaccess in the root directory of typo3 like it is discribed  here: https://docs.typo3.org/p/lochmueller/staticfilecache/main/en-us/Configuration/Htaccess.htm The problem doesn't go away after some time, only restarting php-fpm helped.

Comment: It is a "one-Click-installation" on all-inkl Servers with automatic symlinks when you update e.g. 11.5.10 to 11.5.12, just a handfull extensions together with microtemplate extension.

Comment: This might be a permission problem in ` /www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3temp/var/session/`

Comment: So, in simple words, the problem could be an irregular disrupt (maybe a disconnection of the Internet) and in cause of that the stored hash value in the session folder gets wrong/can't be restored?

Comment: The 2nd error clearly indicates that PHP has not "seen" the file `/www/htdocs/wxxxxxxx/cmstypo3/typo3temp/var/session/5b746183ce7e94a328dc1c5bb6e5598574a6d5c1/hash_6e60e04342f6660702e7abff85ff99d9` at the time when this error occured.

Comment: Workaround:
Erase session data in directory /typo3 tmp/var/session. After that, typo3 seams to work properly again.